# responsive scaling in internet explorer

Tags: javascript

I very need your help. I make composition in Edge Animate with resolution 2300*1914 adjust the responsive scaling to both, after saving I look the composition in browsers. In the Chrome and Opera displaying is correct, but in IE and Firefox displays not correct, I fill the stage in red color, so when I open the composition, the filled stage take proportions 100% - width and height, but resolution 2300*1914 applies like transparent layer, and I have overflow horizontal and vertical

Comment: Are there scrollbars which may make the actual viewport resolution smaller than `2300x1914`?

Comment: http://cyber-x.com.ua/image.jpg  - look at that

Comment: Can you post the code you're using?

Comment: http://cyber-x.com.ua/newfolder.zip